# Create a pdf in python and keep the coordinates of elements

Tags: python, pdf

I need to generate an examination template for an online school website, 
I need to know each coordinates of answers boxes in order to crop them later. 
Is it possible to generate a pdf and get coordinates from each elements inside the pdf ? (Like inserting a black square as an image in the pdf and get his coordinates ?)

I found many libraries to create pdf like pyPdf, pyPdf2,... but i didn't find a way to get coordinates.

Thank you for your suggestions and advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `reportlab`. It would allow you to access coordinates by specifying them yourself:

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
import io
buf = io.BytesIO()
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buf, rightMargin=inch/2, leftMargin=inch/2, topMargin=inch/2, bottomMargin=inch/2, pagesize=letter)
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
answers = []
answers.append(Paragraph('Data for Answer box', styles['Normal']))
doc.build(answers)
school_pdf = open('answers.pdf', 'a')
school_pdf.write(buf.getvalue())
```

Comment: Thank you, this library is perfect !